# Cannot ping from guest to host and viceversa with VirtualBox, CentOS 6.7, Windows 10

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, centos, ping

Cannot ping from guest to host and viceversa.

Guest is CentOS 6.7, default minimal installation + updates. Host is Windows 10 running VirtualBox 5.

Both machines configured with static ip addresses and same subnet. **Windows 10 firewall disabled. CentOS network is bridged**.

`ifconfig` from CentOS:

[image]

`arp -a` from Windows 10 ("statico" means static, "dinamico" means dynamic):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was hit by the same error when I upgraded Virtualbox from 5.0.2 to 5.0.4.

Inspired by this [Reddit Post](https://www.reddit.com/r/virtualbox/comments/3kvlm5/bridged_interface_guest_cannot_see_host_and_vice/) I downgraded virtualbox back to 5.0.2 and the problem disappeared. So it seems to be a bug introduced with 5.0.4.

Comment: I upgraded to 5.0.8. today and everything works as expected, so they seem to have fixed the issue.

Comment: Me too, problem fixed I guess